# É possível listar o nome dos assets em um app Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Estou precisando saber quais os *assets* eu carreguei em um aplicativo em [flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter), para fazer uma reflexão e tomar uma decisão.

Eu sei que eu posso listar quais os *assets* que eu desejo subir para o aplicativo através do `pubspec.yaml`:

```
...

flutter:
  assets:
     - assets/image.png
     - scripts/

...
```

> [Documentação](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets)

No caso acima, estou dizendo que eu quero entregar o arquivo no caminho `assets/image.png` e, também, todos os arquivos dentro do diretório `scripts/`.

Eu posso carregar um *asset* através do `AssetBundle` (como o `rootBundle`, já criado *a priori* no Flutter).

Por exemplo, posso carregar o *asset* `scripts/V1.0__baseline.sql` assim:

```dart
...

// import 'dart:async' show Future;
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('scripts/V1.0__baseline.sql');
}
```

> [Documentação](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets)

Porém, não achei nada na documentação que me permita listar os arquivos dentro da pasta `scripts` para, então, poder fazer algo com eles.

---

Se isso não for possível, também aceito *workarounds*, como gerar um arquivo com a listagem da pasta `scripts` e adicioná-lo como um *asset* (solução semelhante ao que fiz para resolver um [problema análogo no TotalCross](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/issues/428#note_149853147)) através de alguma configuração no `pubspec.yaml` com alguma eventual chamada de script (`bash`/`PowerShell`/`cmd`/`dart`).

Comment: A resposta não lhe auxiliou? O que ficou faltando?

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt tempo hábil para testar, visto que consegui um workaround que amplamente torna essa dificuldade "superada" (de um modo bobo e não flutter de ser). Então até terminar a entrega creio que não conseguirei testar

Answer (score 2):

Não é preciso necessariamente gerar um novo arquivo com o nome dos demais `assets` para então carregá-lo via `AssetBundle`, isso porque o próprio Flutter já faz isso :)

Ao fazer o build da sua aplicação, perceba que é gerado um arquivo `AssetManifest.json` com o registro de todos os assets do app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então levando em consideração um app com 3 imagens de nome `image_1`, `image_2` e `image_3` dentro de `assets/images`:

```dart
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

O conteúdo do arquivo json é o seguinte:

```js
{  
   "packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf":[  
      "packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf"
   ],
   "assets/images/image_1.png":[  
      "assets/images/image_1.png"
   ],
   "assets/images/image_2.png":[  
      "assets/images/image_2.png"
   ],
   "assets/images/image_3.png":[  
      "assets/images/image_3.png"
   ]
}
```

Com isso então basta ler esse arquivo, como você já tem conhecimento, e extrair as informações necessárias, um exempo abaixo:

```dart
Future<List<String>> _findFiles(BuildContext context) async {
  var manifest =
      await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');

  Map map = json.decode(manifest);
  List<String> values =
      map.keys.where((k) => k.contains('assets/image')).toList();
  return Future.value(values);
}
```

Acima, foi feito a leitura do arquivo com `DefaultAssetBundle`, feito o decode do json com `dart:convert` par um Map, e extraído as keys necessárias.

Exemplo completo:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Nome dos Assets'),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _findFiles(context),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final names = snapshot.data;

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: names.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final asset = names[index];

                    return ListTile(title: Text(asset));
                  },
                );
              }

              return Center(
                child: Text('Carregando'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]